# I tried to create Spawner using GameObject / Prefab, and it was cloned, but can not show on the game screen?

Tags: unity, c#

Unity Game
I tried to create Spawner using GameObject, and it was cloned, but can not show those clone on the game screen?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject coin;
    float randX;
    Vector2 whereToSpawn;
    public float spawnRate = 2f;
    float nextSpawn = 0.0f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            randX = Random.Range (-8.4f, 8.4f);
            whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randX, transform.position.y);
            Instantiate(coin, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me!
Any help would be the extreme appreciation!

Comment: Have you tried to find the spawned object in the *Hierarchy* panel and explore why it doesn't appear?

Comment: it still appears in the Hiararchy panel in runtime, but it shows nothing on game screen though.

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe it spawns *behind* the camera? Check the z coordinates.

Comment: If it exists in the *Hierarchy* panel you can locate it in the *Scene* (even if it's invisible or behind the camera or whatever) and look at its properties in the *Inspector* panel to see what's wrong. This is the only way to find it out. All others would be just guessing. BTW are you sure that *x* from -8.4f to 8.4f is within you camera view?

Comment: Another assumption: if your object is absolutely flat, like a sprite, it can be rotated by its edge towards you and therefore invisible in the XY plane. Try changing the camera perspective plane to check.